# how to access $(Build.BuildNumber) from different project in tfs2015

Tags: build, msbuild, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, release-management

There are two projects eg. Project1 and Project2.
Now In project2, we need to create a release definition,in which we need to copy build output of project1's build definition.

Problem is that we could not give artifact as that of Project1 build definition in Project2 release.

If we could access the $(Build.BuildNumber) variable of project1 from Project2, prolem will be solve.

Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: You could build both projects from the same build definition. Then both would share the same "environmental" properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the build number via REST API, simple steps:

1. Create a new powershell script file in your project with this code:

Code:

```
Param(
    [string]$teamProject,
    [string]$collectionURL,
    [string]$buildId,
    [string]$userName,
    [string]$password
    )
$basicAuth = ("{0}:{1}" -f $userName,$password)
$basicAuth = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($basicAuth)
$basicAuth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($basicAuth)
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $basicAuth)}
$url="$($collectionURL)$($teamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$($buildId)?api-version=2.0"
Write-Output $url
Function GetBuildNumber{
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -headers $headers -Method Get
    Write-Output $result.buildNumber
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=anotherBuildNumber;]$($result.buildNumber)"
}
GetBuildNumber
```

2. Check into the source control
3. Queue build and publish artifacts
4. Edit your release definition
5. Add these variables

[image]

6. Add PowerShell task to your release definition.

   Script filename:[your powershell script file in artifact, e.g. $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/PowerShellVnext/TFS2015U2Solution/PowerShellModuleProject1/RestTest.ps1];

   Arguments:  -teamProject $(teamProject) -collectionURL $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri) -buildId $(buildId) -userName $(username) -passwor $(password)

After that the build number value is stored in **anotherBuildNumber** variable.

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the feature to link other team project build artifacts on TFS now, but as a workaround you could add a **Windows Machine File Copy** task in release definition of Project2 to copy the artifacts from Project1. This [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/48d181fe-e107-4201-b8e1-1f49abd9cb55/linking-a-release-definition-to-multiple-artifacts-from-other-team-projects?forum=tfsgeneral) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks Andy-MSFT...The folder we need to copy is created as part of build output, which name contains build number. Since build number from other team project could not be access we can not use Windows Machine File copy as well.

Answer (score 0):

simple, use a little reflection magic

```
var version = typeof(Program).Assembly
              .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>().Version;
```

You can replace the typeof([ClassName]) with any class name you like to get the version from even reflection types. this technique is quite helpful when logging errors as you can get the file versions from dependent assemblies as well, any class that is in scope.

It's not what you asked for, however, I am sure that there are those that need this as well.. if you need the build date you can get that by using:

```
var date = new FileInfo(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location).CreationTime;
```